# Windows Defender might be impacting your build performance

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

After I updated my PyCharm IDE to 19.2.0 from the 19.1.2. I am getting the following warning:

```
"Windows Defender might be impacting your build performance. PyCharm checked 
thefollowing directories:
C:\Workspace\Projects\576_UniversityTwitter 
C:\Users\Burak\.PyCharmCE2019.2\system 
C:\Users\Burak\.gradle
```

Do you think that it is secure, necessary and really improve the performance?

Comment: for sure even if it doesn't its impacting your pc just open task manager and look at the resources Windows Defender is using.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it. Plus, if you have a good AV such as Eset or Kaspersky, you don't even need Defender. Or just use Linux.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to exclude those directories in your Windows Security's Exclusion list.

1. Type **Windows Security** in your windows Search bar
2. Click **Virus & threat protection**
3. Under **Virus & threat protection settings** header, click **Manage Settings**
4. Under **Exclusions** header, click **Add or remove exclusions**
5. Click **Add an exclusion**
6. Select type **Folder**
7. Enter the directory
8. You are done

---

Yes it is secure, necessary and really improves the performance as the real-time scanning is enabled in Windows defender by default.
Read this: [Minimize the impact of antivirus software on build speed](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact).

Comment: Can you elaborate why excluding certain folders will not compromise security?
An attacker could specifically place malicious files in those folders, knowing that the files won't be scanned bei the antivirus software.

Comment: @EliasRabl You're correct, it's something to be concerned about, albeit kept in context considering what those files are, and who theoretically is responsible for them.

Comment: I did this for my project's base folder and also for the AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm folder, yet every time I open the project I still get the same warning. I don't want to just dismiss the notification if it will affect build performance. Is there actually still an issue or is PyCharm just "paranoid"? I already tried their auto-fix feature as well.

Comment: Yes, agree with @doublefelix, I checked the Defender exclusions, they are exactly those that the PyCharm pop-up mentions, and yet that pop-up pops up each time I launch PyCharm... annoying

Comment: For Norton, you can add the files/directories to just the real-time scan exclusion list. This will not impact the nightly file system scans.

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem with Android Studio which is from same company after the recent update. So what you can do is you will get the directory which is causing this error.
Like
[image: You will get the directories here]

Then you need to go to Windows Defender and add these folders to the exclusion in Windows Defender or the antivirus you are using.

Answer (score 8):

I did the above steps with adding exceptions to the defender, but the message in the WebStorm application did not want to disappear.

Running the WebStorm application as administrator helped me.

Comment: Thanks. Running the PHPStorm as administrator was the only thing that helped me!!

Answer (score -1):

As described in the [User guide for Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact):

> #### Optimize Android Studio performance on Windows
>
> ---
>
> Android Studio performance on Windows can be impacted by a variety of
> factors. This section describes how you can optimize Android Studio
> settings to get the best possible performance on Windows.
>
> #### Minimize the impact of antivirus software on build speed
>
> Some antivirus software can interfere with the Android Studio build
> process, causing builds to run dramatically slower. When you run a
> build in Android Studio, Gradle compiles your app’s resources and
> source code and then packages the compiled resources together in an
> APK. During this process, many files are created on your computer. If
> your antivirus software has real-time scanning enabled, the antivirus
> can force the build process to halt each time a file is created while
> the antivirus scans that file.
>
> To avoid this issue, you can exclude certain directories from
> real-time scanning in your antivirus software.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Ven Ren, do you undestand why the edit by Teomerikoo was needed? Why that edit would have been expected by you? And why you should keep that in mind for future posts?