# Windows defender on PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide, windows-defender

Every time I start PyCharm, there is a popup that indicates that Windows Defender is slowing down the system.

When I select to change configuration to Windows Defender, the popup appears again at next PyCharm restarting.

It exists a way to make this change permanent? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude paths from Defender so that Pycharm works better.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58433724/1457859